# PHP file_get_contents errors at 128K

Tags: php

I am searching for clues as to why post requests larger than *128K* are dying with a returned *500* or *404*.

The php script includes similar to this portion

```
$arContext['http']['timeout'] = 60;
$context = stream_context_create($arContext);
$FileContents = file_get_contents('php://input', 0, $context);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "File length = " . strlen($FileContents);
```

Server side:

> post_max_size = 8M
>
> memory_limit = 32M

syslog shows file length is 131702 on these failed posts.

At this point, this seems to only be a problem with satellite connections, but not sure how that plays into the problem.

Wireshark from serverside includes:

```
POST /Farms/somewhere.php?id=lalala HTTP/1.1
Host: nowhere.net
Content-Length: 96
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

.G.c.!.......&.>...&..K..-.)..^B?.(..4XH..veU..kU..w...I..Xr.&C...+^H...`.............x..C=.2...HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 22:32:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.30
Cache-Control: no-transform
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252

10
."5.......E..>..
0

POST /Farms/somewhere.php?id=lalala HTTP/1.1
Host: nowhere.net
Content-Length: 1745376
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

.G.c.!.......&.>.--->data-->Y.I*#WHTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 27 May 2016 22:32:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
Content-Length: 798
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 webmaster@nowhere.net and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at nowhere.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

apache error logs show

```
[Sat May 28 10:47:53 2016] [error] [client nn.nn.176.108] Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70008
[Sat May 28 10:47:53 2016] [error] [client nn.nn.176.108] File does not exist: /home/somewhere/public_html/500.shtml
```

It also seems that H___net is inserting Connection: Keep-Alive in the header.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Added wireshark follow tcp stream from server side.

Comment: Also added server side error log

Comment: Is 128kb perhaps the chunk (block) size used in your transfers?

Comment: No, there isn't any blocks that size.